# Winforms designer: Possible to programmatically achieve Project Variables?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, environment-variables, windows-forms-designer

I'm working in C# Winforms, .net 4.0, and am designing some design-time components.  My goal is to have the designer look for a specific file that resides in (either the project dir or the output dir).

Is there anyway for me to find the values of the following variables from code?

(Outpath)
(ProjectDir)

Comment: I'm assuming you want this design-time, not while whatever project is using these components is actually executing.  I'm not sure enough to post this as an answer because I've never used it, but this LOOKS to me like it might be what you're looking for, art least for the OutputPath.  Does this help?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984523(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This is very promising.  You shoult put this down in the answers so I can mark it when it works out, thanks.

Comment: @DavidStratton, I can't find those variables in-code.

Comment: That's only half the answer you were looking for.  More helful, I think to future visitors, would be if you find the answer to both properties, you can answer your own question.  I wouldn't feel right posting an answer that I'm not pretty sure of.  It was just a guess and a lucky google search.  And if I'm wrong I may be wasting your time.

Comment: You may have to add a refernce to  microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.dll and add a "using" statement for "Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine"

Comment: This is extremely brittle and not well supported.  You really want to use a resource here.

Comment: As of right now, I added my project path as a resource.  I want to avodi this, but I don't know a better solution.  I'm gonna try the vcprojectengine reference and see where that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not so difficult if you can access the EnvDTE80.DTE2 representing your Visual Studio instance. In fact if dte is your instance of DTE2, it's as simple as:

```
foreach (Project prj in dte.Solution.Projects)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Path.GetDirectoryName(prj.FullName));
                    MessageBox.Show(prj.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties.Item("OutputPath").Value.ToString());
                }
```

To get the DTE2 object is easy if you are writing an Add-In, since it is the first parameter passed to OnConnection (the wizard for the add-in projects automatically write code that put it in the _applicationObject variable of the Connect class).

If you have only the component, you can get the Site property, which implements ISite, which is derived from IServiceProvider, and ask it to get the DTE2. If compo is your component:

```
   dte = (DTE2)compo.Site.GetService(typeof(DTE2));
```

Comment: The site service retrieval looks very promising!